# Why is webdriver not defined in my Protractor test case?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

I am trying to use a method as per the [Protractor docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.getCookie). but when I do the API call I get `ReferenceError: webdriver is not defined`. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23053661/protractor-e2e-throwing-webdriver-is-not-defined) is the only other occurence of this that I could find, and it's (rather odd) solution does not work in my case.

My code looks like:

```
'Cookie': webdriver.WebDriver.Options.prototype.getCookie('CookieName')
```

I'm running protractor `version 1.4.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `browser.manage()` is the options interface for the `webdriver.WebDriver.Options` instance.

Please do:

```
browser.manage().getCookie('CookieName');
```

Sorry docs are confusing on this one.

Also, please follow the promise to get the actual value:

```
browser.manage().getCookie('CookieName').then(function(cookieValue) {
    console.log(cookieValue);
});
```

Unless you're doing an expectation in which case it will be resolved for you:

```
expect(browser.manage().getCookie('CookieName')).toEqual('some value');
```

Comment: could you link to the api docs? I can't find the functions that you mention here...